# Insert variable Data into SQL server using python

Tags: python, sql

```
def LiraRateApiCall():
R = requests.get(url)
timestamp = R.json()['buy'][-1][0]/1000
format_date = '%d/%m/%y'
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
buyRate = R.json()['buy'][-1][1]
print(date.strftime(format_date))
print(buyRate)


#ADDDING TO SQL SERVER
conn = odbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
                    'Server=LAPTOP-36NUUO53\SQLEXPRESS;'
                    'Database=test;'
                    'Trusted_connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Data_table (Time1,Price)
                VALUES
                ('date',140),
                ('Date2' , 142)
                ''')
conn.commit()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Data_table')

for i in cursor:
    print(i)
```

How do i pass the variables date and buy rate to the table instead of putting in values liek i did (i put in'date' , 140 for example but i want to pass variables not specific values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to check the driver version that you're using, but what you're looking for is the concept of bind variables. I'd suggest you look into the concept of fast_executemany as well - that should help speed things up. I've edited your code to show how bind variables typically work (using the (?, ?) SQL syntax), but there are other formats out there.

```
def LiraRateApiCall():
R = requests.get(url)
timestamp = R.json()['buy'][-1][0]/1000
format_date = '%d/%m/%y'
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
buyRate = R.json()['buy'][-1][1]
print(date.strftime(format_date))
print(buyRate)


#ADDDING TO SQL SERVER
conn = odbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
                    'Server=LAPTOP-36NUUO53\SQLEXPRESS;'
                    'Database=test;'
                    'Trusted_connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Setup data
data = [('date',140), ('Date2' , 142)]

#Use executemany since we have a list
cursor.executemany('''
                INSERT INTO Data_table (Time1,Price)
                VALUES (?, ?)
                ''', data)

conn.commit()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Data_table')

for i in cursor:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont understand at all your question

If you want to pass the variables:

```
insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO Data_table (Time1,Price) VALUES (' + date + ',' + str(buyRate) + ')'
cursor.execute(insert_sql)
```

If you want to do dynamic Insert:

You can only insert knowing the values ​​or by inserting with a select

```
INSERT INTO table
SELECT * FROM tableAux
WHERE condition;
```

That or you could iterate through the fields you have in a table, extract them and compare it to your variables to do a dynamic insert.

With this select you can extract the columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'table1'
```